# Variables, Square roots, and exponents

Tags: power-series, exponentiation

[image]

Answer : $x^2$

I got $x^n$, shouldn't I be multiplying the variables in the parentheses first. Thus cancelling out the roots and left with $x$ then to the power of n? thus -> $x^n$ ? Please explain step by step.

Comment: FYI, you can write that radical "$\sqrt[n]{x}$" using the notation \sqrt[n]{x}, and you can get the multiplication symbol "$\cdot$" using \cdot

Answer (score 1):

$$
(x^{1/n}*x^{1/n})^n = (x^{2/n})^n = x^2
$$

Comment: When multiplying two variables with the same base we add the exponents.  When we have a power to a power, we multiply those powers.